# How do i put 2 textview in same lime and using datepicker in edittext

Tags: android

I want to add a text in front of "originTxt" and "destinationTxt", both the value are retrieved from database. Everytime i drag a textview before the textview, the textview will not be aligned.
For example the value from database is "China" and "US" ,i want the output to be

> Origin: China
>
> Destination: US

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="171dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Destination"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/destinationTxt" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The next thing i want to user a datepicker to enter the whole date into a string rather than typing manually. Can I use a datepicker inside an EditText?

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dateEditText"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:hint="Moving Date" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are wanting the second TextView to the right of the first. So in the second TextView you can put android:layout_toRightOf="@id/nameText"

Comment: I want to add a new textview on the left of each textview

Comment: Hooyan, just put that text where you want it and then it the ones that you want to the right of it but that bit in.

Comment: thanks! I just found out that i should use relativelayout rather than linearlayout

Comment: Yea that would help, depends on what you are trying to do. But yea hopefully that helped!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the LinearLayout orientation to be horizontal and add them the separately into your linear layout which is vertical.

You are not able to do it since the your linear layout supports only vertical alignment.

Hope this logic resolved your problem.

Now for datepicker using edit text use the following code.

```
dateEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      datePickerDialog.show();

    }
});
datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        dateEditText.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
    }

},newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}
```

Add that in your Activity class your date picker doubt will also be resolved.
Thank You

Comment: For making the alignment as you are telling..There are plenty of ways. One among those ways is the logic which i mentioned above.